# Modify given regular expression for German mobile numbers

Tags: python, regex, match

I have a regular expression (regex) which matches German mobile numbers.

The expression looks like this:

`[^\d]((\+49|0049|0)\s?(1|9)[1567]\d{1,2}([ \-/]*\d){7,8})(?!\d)`

It covers number formats like this and many more:

```
+4915368831169
+49 15207955279
+49 1739341284
```

As you can see in the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w425Os/2), the regular expression covers a whole range of possible formats, but unfortunately matches to both `0 910 0 910 -77 -1` and `0 910 0 910 -75 0` which are not German mobile numbers.

How can I modify the regular expression in a way that the regex still matches the German mobile numbers provided in the demo but will not match the given sequence of numbers?

Comment: Just remove the `\-` if you don't want to allow the dash inside the number?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew According to your example the numbers ``015731294508``
and ``015735995842`` are not matched anymore. Please check the provided regex demo.

Comment: @MSpiller Well, this would be the simples approach. But removing ``\-`` has negative impact on the other formats.   Please check the provided regex demo.

Comment: Why don't you only match `-` when it is preceded by a digit? https://regex101.com/r/61l4Fr/1 or not preceded by a whitespace char https://regex101.com/r/c26RHW/1

Comment: Maybe start with describing what you think is a _valid_ number...

Comment: @MSpiller The format is complex to desribe which is why I provided many examples of valid and invalid formats. @ TheFourthBird This approach looks promising according to the provided demo. Let me try to understand it!

Comment: Another way is to cancel the match if there is space + `-` + digit: https://regex101.com/r/w425Os/3

Comment: Or shorter `[^\d]((\+49|0049|0)\s?([19])[1567]\d{1,2}(?:\d[ /-]*){6,7}\d)(?!\d)`  https://regex101.com/r/E471Ha/1

Comment: Based on my specific problem the answer from  @Thefourthbird is the most attractive to me. The regex fully matches my provided demo. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match 6-7 times a digit followed by optional spaces `/` or `-` and match a digit at the end before the negative lookahead.

With the capture groups:

```
[^\d]((\+49|0049|0)\s?([19])[1567]\d{1,2}(?:\d[ /-]*){6,7}\d)(?!\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E471Ha/1)

Without capture groups:

```
(?<!\d)(?:\+49|0049|0)\s?[19][1567]\d{1,2}(?:\d[ /-]*){6,7}\d(?!\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P6rZxf/1)